# Audio Fingerprinting implementation on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, fingerprinting

It's the first time I post a question in a blog, but it seems to me this is the best resource on the web for that.

I'm looking for a way to implement audio fingerprinting in an application for iPhone. I had a look at the lastfm fingerprinter, being that I already use other lstfm api calls, but porting it to the iphone seems to be a mess and I'm quiet sure that it would be highly inefficient.

Should I give the search for now as I am looking for a free service ,I'm a young private developer and don't have sufficient economic resources for a payed service. This is also the reason for which I cannot install the library on my web server and run it remotely, sending just the audio data to it. The hosting I rely on dosen't allow me to install third party applications...

Music Brainz seems to be a solution, but not quiet sure on how to obtain the fingerprint...

Any suggestions, hint, tips, links, search queries, anything?

Thanks in advance!

Christian

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Echoprint](http://echoprint.me),  an open source audio fingerprinting service provided by Echonest.

[Here](https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-ios-sample) is the iOS example they provide on their echoprint github repo.